# How do I set up PyOpenGL with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyopengl

I am wanting to set up several 3D mathematical projects with python. The best way I can see to render these is with PyOpenGL. I also want to run it in PyQt5, so that I can have GUI’s along side the render. All the information I can find is either using PyGame or QtDesigner. I would like to work without QtDesigner. Does anyone know where I could find a tutorial on how to set this up?

EDIT:

I managed to get some web scrounging done. I found the following code at https://pythonprogramming.net/community/37/Cube%20rotation%20with%20pyopengl%20and%20pyqt/ where the author asks for help regarding it not running. he says the following about it:

> I'm very new to python. I have a problem with my code, it's a very simple rotating cube. I don't have any problem with this cube code with pygame screen but when I use it with pyqt (or Qt designer widgets), it runs but it shows nothing!!!

I copied his code into my IDe, then saved it as `cubes.py`. I opened up a CMD instance in thae directory of the file and called it. It opened a tiny black Qt window in the middle of the screen:
[image: the result of the code]

When I try to resize the window by dragging the corner, it throws a *deep* traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Python\cubes\cubes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'

C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Python\cubes>cubes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Python\cubes\cubes.py", line 56, in paintGL
    glEnd()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\exceptional.py", line 45, in glEnd
    return baseFunction( )
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 234, in glCheckError
    baseOperation = baseOperation,
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1280,
        description = b'invalid enumerant',
        baseOperation = glEnd,
        cArguments = ()
)
```

Here is his code, unmodified:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL import *
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys,time

class MainWindow(QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.widget = glWidget(self)
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

class glWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)

        self.verticies = (
            (1,-1,-1),
            (1,1,-1),
            (-1,1,-1),
            (-1,-1,-1),
            (1,-1,1),
            (1,1,1),
            (-1,-1,1),
            (-1,1,1))
        self.edges = (
            (0,1),
            (0,3),
            (0,4),
            (2,1),
            (2,3),
            (2,7),
            (6,3),
            (6,4),
            (6,7),
            (5,1),
            (5,4),
            (5,7))

    def paintGL(self):
        while True:
            #glRotatef(1,3,1,1)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            glBegin(GL_LINE)
            for self.edge in self.edges:
                for self.vertex in self.edge:
                    glVertex3fv(self.verticies[self.vertex])
            glEnd()
            glFlush()
            time.sleep(1)       

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -50.0, 50.0)
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

    def initializeGL(self):

        #glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gluPerspective(45,800/600,0.1,50.0)
        glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5)
        glRotatef(0,0,0,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I once developed an interactive 3D program using PyOpenGL and PyQt5.
Here's the spike code of that time.
I wish this could be helpful to you.

```py
import sys
import math
from array import array

from OpenGL import GL

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget

from shader import ShaderProgram


class Window (QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello')


class GLWidget (QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(1200, 1000)

    def initializeGL(self):
        GL.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)  # it's also possible.

        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        # GL.glEnable(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

        self._createVertexBuffer()

        self.program = ShaderProgram('hello.vert', 'hello.frag')
        self.program.use()

        self.frontTexture = self._createTexture('tex.png')
        self.backTexture = self._createTexture('back-tex.jpg')

         # set texture units

        GL.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.frontTexture)
        GL.glUniform1i(GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program.getProgram(), b'frontTexture'), 0)

        GL.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE1)
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.backTexture)
        GL.glUniform1i(GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program.getProgram(), b'backTexture'), 1)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self._draw()

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        GL.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side, side)

    def _createTexture(self, texFilePath):
        qImage = QImage(texFilePath)

        texture = QGLWidget.bindTexture(self, qImage, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_RGBA)

        GL.glGenerateMipmap(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        return texture

    def _createVertexBuffer(self):
        vertices = array('f', [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0]).tobytes()
        colors = array('f', [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]).tobytes()
        indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2]
        texCoords = array('f', [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0]).tobytes()

        self.vertices = vertices
        self.colors = colors
        self.indices = indices
        self.texCoords = texCoords

    def _draw(self):

        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, self.vertices)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, self.colors)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, self.texCoords)

        GL.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.indices)

        GL.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)
        GL.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code! When I get the chance, I will dig through it.

Comment: That's 5 years old code. But when I ran it on Ubuntu 18.04 today, it worked fine. Good luck.

Comment: what is the shader program used for? Can I run the GL render without it?

Comment: I used some shader programs on it (Python + OpenGL). And you can do whatever with Python as much as C++.